# Deploying offline with EF code-first migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We develop an intranet web-app running off of the Microsoft stack that gets updated on client networks from time-to-time. Updates are done manually with two components:

- Installing/extracting the new application files over the top of the old ones
- Executing an SQL script that runs the deltas between the previous and current version

We are in the process of migrating our codebase from ASP.NET WebForms / ADO.NET to ASP.NET MVC / Entity Framework 6.1. We are using code-first migrations for development, with automatic migrations setup.

So my question is: how do we now translate that into production? Most posts around the web seem to contemplate using WebDeploy or a similar connected approach, but our files are distributed (via email, or download) then installed 'offline'. Is there a way we can leverage the migrations to have the database updated, or are we stuck using SQLDelta or equivalent to generate a change script to be executed on the client?

With the power of Entity Framework to abstract away many of the physical aspects of storage it seems counter-intuitive that we would be reduced to an implementation-specific approach for deployment. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite easy.

Migrations has commands that can be run in the Package Manager Console to create SQL script for appplying migrations, so that you can save them and email them to your customers. These are the minimum required parameters for doing this (you'll probably have to add other parameters to specify some other options):

```
Update-Database -SourceMigration "Origin" -TargetMigration "Destination" -Script
```

With this command you're telling that you want to create an script which can transform a database on the "Origin" state into a database on the "Destination" state, where those are the names of the corresponding migrations. You'll get a full SQL script to apply those changes.

For this scenary I prefer to create manual Migrations, because I have more control on their names, so that it's easier for me to identify the origin and destination migrations.

By the way, if you need extra help on the required parameters, you can run

```
Update-Database -?
```

And, if you read the last lines of the output, you'll see there other options:

```
To see the examples, type: "get-help Update-Database -examples".
For more information, type: "get-help Update-Database -detailed".
For technical information, type: "get-help Update-Database -full".
```

Of course, this appply for the other commands.

Comment: Great answer, very informative and concise, thankyou